# How can I use the ' - symbol in concat function in SQL

Tags: sql

I have values in the SQL statement as follows, for example

```
'$.Company_ID'
```

Important are the symbol: `**'**`. I also need to have this as string.

So I try to get it like this:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('**'$.**',+ AttsData.[key], '**'**') AS XYZ
FROM
    Testtable
```

So as result I want to get a column which has values like

```
**'$.Company_ID'**
```

But it is not possible to concat the symbol `**'**` like `'**'**'`.

Do you have an idea how I can solve this problem.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: yes i use MS SQL Server

Comment: i get the message 451´: A collation mismatch between "Latin1_General_BIN2" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the json_value operator occurring in the 3 column of the SELECT statement cannot be resolved.

Comment: my SQL Statement look like follows:

Comment: Select
a.ID,
a.Conccatspalte,
JSON_VALUE(a.Customwerte, a.Conccatspalte ) AS TestCus
from
(
Select  
[test].ID AS ID,
[test].JSONColumn AS Customwerte,
AttsData.[key] AS ABC,
AttsData.[Value] AS Wert,
 CONCAT('''$.', AttsData.[key], '''') AS Conccatspalte 
from 
[test]  OUTER APPLY OPENJSON ([test].JSONColumn) AS AttsData
) a

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to escape the quotes (which you commonly do by doubling up) - also not sure why you have `+` as part of your `concat`, try:

```
 CONCAT('**''$.**', AttsData.[key], '**''**')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. now i get the correct result. I have used it like: CONCAT('''$.', AttsData.[key], '''') AS Conccatspalte and i get this result.

Comment: Do you also have experience in JSON_VALUE? How can i use the content of this column as JSON Path in JSON_VALUE. If JSON_VALUE(a.Customwerte, a.Conccatspalte ) AS TestCus

Comment: if i execute this i get a mistake. a. Customwerte column has a JSON. I want to prove whether the values of the column a.Conccatspalte exists in this JSON_VALUE Query.

Comment: Normally you make query like: SELECT JSON_VALUE(a.Customwerte, '$.Company_ID' ) AS TestCus --> This query give a result. The values of my column a.Conccatspalte have now the same syntax.

Comment: That's a different question, by all means ask another and as many as you need!

Comment: ok thank you ver much for your support